# Requesting AWS limit increase of EC2 instances - how long does it take?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need a few p2 instances but my limit is 0, I submitted a request about 7 hours ago but it's still 'unassigned', so probably no one ever paid it any attention. How long does it normally take to increase my instance limit and is there a way to expedite it?

Comment: Yah my requests typically 24 hours, I am on unpaid support. P2, pricey ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to say it depends on your support level. Assuming the basic level, it's 24 hours I believe.  If you are an enterprise you can expedite by going to your account team (which they now do have for larger customers or opportunities).

Comment: I believe there is an automated process for approval of EC2 limit increases, at least for small requests. I am on Basic Support and all of my small requests increasing F1.x2 and F1.x16 were approved within a minute. Also AWS says it takes up to 30 minutes to be reflected in your account. But in my experience, I was able to use new limits in less than 5 minutes after approval.

Answer (score 4):

Just do document my experience: it took Amazon 17 hours just to acknowledge my request, which they escalated to the Service Team so it will take another 24/48 hours.

Answer (score 4):

I signed up for AWS and immediately requested a limit increase for p2. It took them about 48 hours to acknowledge my request and escalate to the service team. The email says that the service team could take up to 48 hours from now.

Answer (score 2):

Request limits don't take that long except pre-warming of load balancers. 
Best way is to fill up the request increase form and then choose contact method as phone. This way, you get a call from AWS, an assistant is assigned to you and your request is taken care in max 15 minutes.

Comment: I also found contacting by phone to be very fast. The person I talked to wasn't able to fulfill the request for me, but apparently did something to escalate the ticket as I got mine resolved that day.